# ConverterNotFoundException while trying to SELECT with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I'm using this method

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.id, p.picture, p.name, p.age, p.info, p.city, p.state, p.status\n" +
        "FROM owner_pet as op\n" +
        "INNER JOIN lost_pet as p on op.id_pet =?1\n" +
        "WHERE op.id_owner =?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<LostPetEntity> find(Integer id);
```

When I'm using this query on MySQL workbench, it brings me a LostPetEntity table
[image]
 but in my spring application it drops me this exception:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
>   [fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LostPetEntity] for value ‘{1,
>   Dogola, 1, Nova União, /r/ban, RO, NOTICED, defaultvalue}’; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to
>   type [fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LostPetEntity]] with
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to
>   type [fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LostPetEntity]

---

LostPetEntity.class:

```
package fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity;

import fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.pets.PetDTO;
import fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.pets.Status;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "lost_pet")
@Data
public class LostPetEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String picture;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String age;
    @Column
    private String info;
    @Column
    private String city;
    @Column
    private String state;
    @Column
    private String status;

    public LostPetEntity(PetDTO dto) {
        this.picture = dto.getPicture();
        this.name = dto.getName();
        this.age = dto.getAge();
        this.info = dto.getInfo();
        this.city = dto.getCity();
        this.state = dto.getState();
        this.status = String.valueOf(Status.MISSING);
    }

    public LostPetEntity() {
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you mapped `LostPetEntity` at all?

Comment: It would help If you would share the `LostPetEntity` class

Comment: Sorry! I forgot that. Updating right now.

Answer (score -1):

**Change your code to this.**

```
List<Object[]> find(Integer id);
```